# please,find the limit of $x$

Tags: limits

please,find the limit of $x$  when

$x=u^{-\frac{1}{\alpha}}$

where ${0}\le u\le{1}$   and $\alpha>0$

i have found the limit of $x$ is also ${0}\le x\le{1}$

when $u=0$ then $x=0$ since  $x=0^{-\frac{1}{\alpha}}=0$

when $u=1$ then $x=1$ since  $x=1^{-\frac{1}{\alpha}}=1$

but the book which i am reading showing that the range of $x\ge{1}$

where is my wrong?

would you like to help me finding the limit?

please, show your works step by step.

If you have doubt on my question then kindly explain me how the power distribution of statistics ranges from $1 to \inf$
when X follows power distribution & U follows standard uniform distribution & $X=U^{-\frac{1}{\alpha}}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's have proper notations:
$$
\forall (u,a),\; 0 < u \leq 1,\; a > 0,\quad f_a(u) = \frac{1}{u^a}
$$

What did I do? I adopted a fraction-notation because of the minus sign in the exponent, and I posed $a = \frac{1}{\alpha}>0$.

Now I suppose I don't need to prove that given any exponent $a>0$, for any $u\in]0,1],\ u^a\in]0,1]$, and so $f_a(u)\geq 1$.

Comment: Thank you. But what was the wrong in my process .

Comment: how have you understood the proper notation ,ie, $0 < u \leq 1$? why have you denote $x$ as $f_a(u)\geq 1$ ? why the suffix is $a$?

Comment: if $a<0$ then what will be happened? will there be any change ? if so then why?

Comment: Well, $\frac{1}{0^+}=+\infty$, so the case $u=0$ had to be excluded (unless we decide $+\infty$ can be reached, which would also be valid). As far as $f_a(u)$ it's not more valid than your notation, it's just clearer :) The subscript in $f_a$ means that $a$ is a parameter, whereas $u$ is the named variable of the function $f_a$. The difference is that $f_a$ is a function for all $a$, and $f_a(u)$ is a number for all $(a,u)$.

Comment: If $a<0$, then you just have to consider the last sentence without the last part; we would have $f_a(u)\in[0,1]$ for all $0\leq u\leq 1$.

Comment: Actually i am reading probability distribution. in some distributions, such as, Uniform, Binomial etc, the book noted the probability as $f_X(x)$ while $X$ is the random variable. But in some other distribution they used the parameter of the distribution as subscript , ie,  $f_a(x)$     where $a$ is the parameter. why have they done so? i was accustomed to the subscript as random variable , ie,   $f_X(x)$ while $X$ ,not to the parameter,ie,  $f_a(x)$ while $X$  ;     where $a$ is the parameter

Comment: $f_X$ is a usual notation for the probability density function (pdf) of a random variable $X$. It depends on which probability distribution we're talking about; if the distribution has two parameters $(\theta,\phi)$, then $f_{\theta,\phi}$ is just a more precise notation for the same pdf, which indicates it has two parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much. i have found answers of my all questions.you are really a good teacher.Thank you again.

Comment: No problem :) I you get involved on this forum, you'll find a lot of people are much better than me here ;) If I may, try to improve your english a little, your questions weren't always easy to understand, it will serve you too :)

Comment: i'll try to improve my english. Thank you .